# AngularJs. How get object information from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a problem with reading information from json.

**database.json:**

```
{
  "records":[
    {
      "Name":"Mehul",
      "Age":"18"
    },
    {
      "Name":"Alex",
      "Age":"128"
    }
  ]
}
```

**controller.js:**

```
this.$http.get('http://localhost:82/database.json').
        then((data) => {        
            this.$scope.persons = data;
             console.log(this.$scope.persons);
        });
```

**view.html:**

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
      {{ person.Name + ' : ' + person.Age }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

In my browser, there is no result. I get:

[image]

When I  change a line in controller like:

```
this.$scope.persons = data.records;
```

I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the data property of it,

```
 $scope.persons = data.data.records;
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/oFo6uNTWTYGgpJoJCJ8r?p=preview)**